# Silverlight chart, change binding property at run time?

Tags: c#, wpf, silverlight

first off the example code, I have a class like so

```
Public class SomeClass
{
  Public int indexNum {get;set;}
  Public int value1 {get;set;}
  Public int value2 {get;set;}

  Public SomeClass(){}
}
```

I create a list and fill it.

```
List<SomeClass> AList = new List<SomeClass>();

for(int i =0; i < 5; i++)
{
  AList.Add(new SomeClass()
      {
        indexNum = i,
        Value1 = i * 5,
        Value2 = i * 2
      });
}

MyChart.DataContext = AList;
```

and the binding in the chart like so

```
DependentValueBinding="{Binding Value1}" IndependentValueBinding="{Binding indexNum}"
```

Now on the page there will be a button at the top. When I push the button I would like the DependentValueBinding to switch from Value1 to Value2. Can this all be done in the xaml code or do I have to create all the bindings in the code behind?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [XamlWriter.Save](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms590450.aspx) method to serialize an object.

And you can use [XamlReader.Load](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms590388.aspx) method to deserialize the a XAML string.

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't find how to do all this in xaml but in code behind its just as simple as this

```
((ColumnSeries)MyChart.Series[0]).DependentValueBinding = 
   new System.Windows.Data.Binding("Value2");
```